# Resolution of dipole moment into components

Tags: electric-fields, dipole, dipole-moment

In the derivation that involves finding the electric field due to a dipole at a general point on a plane in which the dipole lies, the following procedure is followed:

1. Resolve the dipole moment into two components that are concentric with the original dipole moment such that one component (P<sub>r</sub>) is directed towards the point of observation and the other component (P<sub>t</sub>) is perpendicular to P<sub>r</sub> (refer the figure below).
2. Calculate the electric fields due to P<sub>r</sub> and P<sub>t</sub> individually and then take the vector sum of the two fields to get the required answer, i.e., the electric field due to the original dipole at the point of observation.

[image]

What is the justification for this method? In other words, what is the proof of the following statement:

> Replacing two concentric dipoles with another single concentric dipole, without changing the dipole moment of the system, would make no difference in the electric field at distant points.

Comment: That logic sounds basically backwards to me! The proof this works is that you need to calculate it exactly, and then you see the error terms fall off faster than the dipole field. (The general calculation here is called the multipole expansion, and you’re only changing multipoles higher than the dipole.)

Comment: But if you don’t even know what the dipole field is at this point, the logic as stated is not good.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. A dipole is two equal and opposite charges separated by a distance. There is only one dipole in both cases. And they have the same centre.

Comment: @sammygerbil : I am sorry. I don't understand what "two cases" you are talking about. I wanted to know if there was a justification for this method of resolving a dipole moment into its components and then calculating the electric field due to these components and then adding them up vectorially to get the final answer.

Comment: The two charges A, B form a dipole. That is the 1st case. Their dipole moment is $p=qd$ where $d$ is the distance AB. Dipole moment is the same if $q$ increases while $d$ decreases in proportion. In the limit you shrink $d$ to zero while increasing $q$, all the time keeping the product $p$ constant. In this way you can replace the dipole AB with a "point" dipole located at midpoint O. This is the 2nd case.

Comment: Have you tried working through the derivation, starting with 2 point charges at A and B, as knzhou suggested?

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe a bit of a cheat as it's been implemented by the source you quote. In essence, it's because the electric field produced by a point dipole with dipole moment $\mathbf p$ produces an electrostatic potential
$$
V(\mathbf r) = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{\mathbf p\cdot\mathbf r}{r^3}
$$
that is a linear function of the dipole moment $\mathbf p$; this then extends directly to the electric field. And, since it's linear, we can decompose $\mathbf p$ as any vector sum that we find convenient, find their electric fields, and add them back up to get the totoal field.

But, of course, that logic only works once you've actually found the electrostatic response to a point dipole, which you need to calculate explicitly before you can apply the linearity argument.